# Misaligned form elements with Google add-on stylesheet - input boxes side by side

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, google-apps, add-on

I am trying to create a form with simple styling in Google Apps Script.

When adding the Google add-on stylesheet the text input and select boxes become misaligned. I need them to sit side by side.

[JS Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jjetcc88/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">

<style>

select {
width: 80%;
}

.width-10 {
width: 10%;
}

</style>


<form>
<div class="options" id="option1">

<input type="text" class="width-10" id="user-input1" value="" tabindex=8>
<select id="user-input6" tabindex=1></select><br>

<input type="text" class="width-10" id="user-input2" value="" tabindex=9>
<select id="user-input7" tabindex=2></select><br>

</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the official style sheet for Google Add-ons, you can use the `inline` class.  This will put text input fields and select option lists side by side.

```
<div class="inline form-group">
  <label for="email">Your email:</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@gmail.com" value="example@gmail.com" required>
</div>

<div class="inline form-group">
  <label for="eventName">What's the topic?</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eventName" value="App Testing" required>
</div>
```

You may need to remove your CSS in the `<style>` tag

Comment: thanks for the response, but unfortunately it did not resolve the issue. The misalignment only seems to occur with 'select' elements when the value is blank. Excluding the blank option seems to be a stopgap measure. Not to sure why this would be necessary though as the misalignment only occurs when the Google stylesheet is in use.